# Google Cloud Endpoint package myApi does not exist - Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to add a Google Cloud Endpoint to my Android Application. In my `EndpointAsyncTask` class I use `MyApi` importing it like so:

`import com.example.adamzarn.myapplication.backend.myApi.MyApi;`

When I run my project I get this error:

> Error:(8, 56) error: package
>   com.example.adamzarn.myapplication.backend.myApi does not exist

However, it does exist:

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `build.gradle` file in the module where your `EndpointAsyncTask` class is located. Make sure the dependency to your `backend` module is correct, and ensure there are no conflicts or duplicates. It should be like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: 'backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

This ensures your module can see the `backend` module.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin.

Comment: I have my `EndpointsAsyncTask` class in my app module and this is in my dependencies: `compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')` and `compile project(path: ':backend')`

Comment: try removing `project(path: ':backend')`